# How to get the properties from the DOM Window object only? (Without specifying them individually)

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to get the properties from the DOM Window object.

I don't want to access them individually, e.g.

```
var x = window.innerWidth;
```

Is there a way to just get the properties without also getting the many Window object methods?

If you could imagine, something like this:

```
var props = window.properties; // contains all the Window object properties
```

Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat confusing, but you want to list all properties on window, that aren't functions ?

Comment: I want to assign the properties to a new variable. So the Window object has many properties such as Window.innerHeight, Window.innerWidth, etc. I'd like to mass assign these to a new variable. I don't want the Window object methods though...

Comment: That sounds like an X/Y problem, why do you need to do this ?

Comment: I need to send the Window properties across a network. I don't want to just send the Window object itself as it's too big...

Comment: You have to mention each property individually. You would probably want to get `window.innerHeight`, `window.innerWidth`, `window.scrollY` and `window.scrollY` to send to your server.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the *own enumerable properties* of an object, including `window` with `Object.keys`.

```
Object.keys(window)
```

then just filter on type

```
Object.keys(window).filter(function(x) {
    return typeof window[x] !== 'function';
});
```

If you need properties in the prototype chain as well, you can use a `for...in` loop instead.

```js
Object.keys(window).filter(function(x) {
    // exluding properties that would throw an error here
    return ['frame', 'cache'].indexOf(x) === -1 ||
           typeof window[x] !== 'function';
}).forEach(function(y) {
    document.body.innerHTML += y + '<br>';
});
```

To assign to a new variable

```
var obj = {};

Object.keys(window).filter(function(x) {
    return typeof window[x] !== 'function';
}).forEach(function(y) {
    obj[y] = window[y];
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This does get all the properties, but it gets all the custom properties too. Is there any way to get just the default Window properties? The basic stuff like innerHeight, etc.

Comment: @TomBrock - No, not unless you create a list of the properties you want

Comment: Cheers. Would you mind telling me an efficient way to do that?

Comment: You'll need a list of the properties you want to get, like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/f4hbkao3/

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to just get the properties without also getting the
>   many Window object methods?

Assuming that you want to get only properties and not methods - You can check `typeof` to see if a property value is of type `function`

```
for ( var propName in window )
{
   if ( ( typeof window[propName]) != "function")
   {
      console.log( window[propName] );
   }
}
```

a lot of these values will be null, so you can introduce an extra check

```
for ( var propName in window )
{
   if ( window[propName] && ( typeof window[propName]) != "function")
   {
      console.log( window[propName] );
   }
}
```